# How to make a jquery function work with and without .resize()

Tags: jquery, resize

My head can't get around the logic of this one.

This makes my function fire when the window is resized to below 1200px

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var breakpoint = 1200;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if (parseInt($(window).width()) < breakpoint) {
            ...do something with my function here...
        }
    })
})
```

But what if the window isn't being resized. For example it's just being viewed on a tablet or mobile phone which is less than 1200px?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In that case your logic would still be applied as the window size is < 1200. I'd suggest using CSS media queries for this. It's hardware accelerated, better separation of concerns and you can also target certain devices by their pixel ratio: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @Rory - Ok. But why does my function only happen after a short delay on devices <1200? How can I prevent the delay?

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function(){ ... }).trigger('resize')`

Comment: The delay is known as a FOUC, and is caused by the inherent delay in waiting for the DOM to be ready before any jQuery/JS code is applied - another reason I suggested doing this using CSS only

Comment: @Rory - the delay only happens when I use .resize(). Otherwise, no delay!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 1200) {
        ...do something with my function here...
    }
 });
```